# Multiprocessing - using an array across multiple processes

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, multiprocessing

I am new to the world of multiprocessing, I believe I have the processing part down but I am running into an issue that I do not quite understand.

I am using a Raspberry Pi and taking a user input from a keypad and trying to have a constant display of the code typed on a 4-digit 7-segment display.

Using the following code in mu I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/mu_code/Programs/multiprocessing_display.py", line 125, in <module>
    displayArr = multiprocessing.Array('d', splitToDisplay(user_input))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/context.py", line 141, in Array
    ctx=self.get_context())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 88, in Array
    obj = RawArray(typecode_or_type, size_or_initializer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 65, in RawArray
    type_ = type_ * len(size_or_initializer)
TypeError: len() of unsized object
>>> 
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

Code:

```
import time
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from ctypes import c_char_p

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Keypad GPIO variables
L1 = 19
L2 = 13
L3 = 6
L4 = 5

C1 = 22
C2 = 27
C3 = 17
C4 = 26

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(L1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(L2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(L3, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(L4, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(C1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(C2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(C3, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(C4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

user_input = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
code = ['5', '9', '7', '2']

delay = 0.005
displayNum = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
toDisplay = displayNum

# Digits:   1,  2,  3,  4
selDigit = [4, 16, 20, 21]

# Define GPIO ports to use
display_list = [18, 24, 7, 25, 1, 23, 8]
# disp.List ref: A, B,  C,  D, E,  F, G

digitDP = 14
# DOT = GPIO 14

# Setting up GPIO pins as outputs
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
for pin in display_list:
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)  # setting pins for segments
for pin in selDigit:
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)  # setting pins for digit selector
GPIO.setup(digitDP, GPIO.OUT)  # setting dot pin
GPIO.setwarnings(True)

# Array segment 0 activates digit 0
arrSeg = [
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]]

# 4 Digit 7 Segment display functions
def splitToDisplay(toDisplay):  # splits string to digits to display
    arrToDisplay = list(toDisplay)
    for i in range(len(arrToDisplay)):
        if arrToDisplay[i] == ".": arrToDisplay[(i-1)] = arrToDisplay[(i-1)] + arrToDisplay[i]  # dots are concatenated to previous element
    while "." in arrToDisplay: arrToDisplay.remove(".")  # array items containg dot char alone are removed
    arrToDisplay = np.array(map(float, arrToDisplay))
    return arrToDisplay

def showDisplay(digit):
    for i in range(0, 4):
        sel = [1, 1, 1, 1]
        sel[i] = 0
        GPIO.output(selDigit, sel)  # Activates selected digit
        if digit[i].replace(".", "") == " ":  # space disables digit
            GPIO.output(display_list, 0)
            continue
        numDisplay = int(digit[i].replace(".", ""))
        GPIO.output(display_list, arrSeg[numDisplay])  # Segments are activated according to digit mapping
        if digit[i].count(".") == 1:
            GPIO.output(digitDP, 1)
        else:
            GPIO.output(digitDP, 0)
        time.sleep(delay)

# Keypad functions
def readLine(line, characters):  # Reads the users input
    GPIO.output(line, GPIO.HIGH)
    if(GPIO.input(C1) == 1):
        print(characters[0])
        user_input.append(characters[0])
    elif(GPIO.input(C2) == 1):
        print(characters[1])
        user_input.append(characters[1])
    elif(GPIO.input(C3) == 1):
        print(characters[2])
        user_input.append(characters[2])
    elif(GPIO.input(C4) == 1):
        print(characters[3])
        user_input.append(characters[0])
    GPIO.output(line, GPIO.LOW)

def enterPasscode():  # Creates an array of the users inputted numbers
    user_input.clear()
    print("Please enter your 4 digit passcode:")
    while len(user_input) != 4:
        readLine(L1, ["1", "2", "3", "A"])
        readLine(L2, ["4", "5", "6", "B"])
        readLine(L3, ["7", "8", "9", "C"])
        readLine(L4, ["*", "0", "#", "D"])
        time.sleep(0.2)
    print("You entered: " + user_input[0] + " " + user_input[1] + " " + user_input[2] + " " + user_input[3])


displayArr = multiprocessing.Array('d', splitToDisplay(user_input))


def display(displayNum):
    showDisplay(splitToDisplay(displayNum))

displayProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=display, args=(displayArr,))

def keypad(displayNum):
    while True:
        enterPasscode()
        displayNum = splitToDisplay(user_input)
        if np.array_equal(code, user_input):
            print("Correct Passcode!")
            break
        else:
            print("Incorrect Passcode")
            continue

keypadIntake = multiprocessing.Process(target=keypad, args=(displayArr,))

try:
    keypadIntake.start()
    print(user_input)
    showDisplay(splitToDisplay(displayNum))
    displayProcess.start()
    displayProcess.join()
    displayProcess.terminate()
    displayProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=display)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\Application Stopped!")
```

Comment: search for examples with `multiprocessing.shared_memory` and `numpy` arrays

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do but I keep running into similar issues of my array indexs and lengths so I thought I would try here